# Installing Magento 1.6 on stubborn Windows host

Tags: windows, magento, hosting, upgrade

I have a stubborn (or maybe inexperienced would be a nicer word) Windows host on which I'm trying to install Magento. They have a Plesk interface which allows me to install either Magento 1.4.1 or 1.5.1. But as I've had image upload problems with 1.5 that have been fixed in 1.6, I want to use 1.6 obviously.

The host's support were helpful but unwilling to install 1.6 for me, their web applications are provided by a 3rd party so my guess is that they'd need to pay them for the 1.6 installer. I don't understand... Also they have no way of letting me connect via SSH.

Anyway I've installed a fresh Magento 1.5 on the host, installed Magento 1.6 on my home PC, tried exporting the 1.6 database and importing it into the 1.5 database but it failed to import. I copied the 1.6 files over to the host and navigating to the URL gives me a "The service is unavailable." message.

What a pain. There are lots of threads on the Magento website regarding upgrading a 1.5 installation to 1.6 but mostly involving Pear or Mage or SSH or... Surely there must be an easier way!?

**Does anyone have an ideas of an easy way to install Magento 1.6 on there?**

---

**Edit:**

I tried @clockworkgeek suggestion of using the 'downloader'.

From a clean install of 1.5, I went to /downloader and logged in, typed the extension key "http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Mage_All_Latest" and clicked Proceed.

It started installing and looks great. But then this:

```
CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Lib_Varien 1.6.1.0 depends on PHP extensions: Array

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::isTableExists()
```

Gah, stinky. Then when I navigated to /downloader again, I get this:

```
dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract
```

It's totally broken now. Sob :(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from an install of 1.5;

- **Do not touch the database**. You might want to start afresh in case some changes were made on your last attempt.
- Navigate to yoursite.com/downloader
- Paste in this extension key

  > http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Mage_All_Latest

  ...and click Install then Proceed. The relevant files will be updated.
- On the next page request the database is updated to match the versions of the new files.

---

Alternatively you could just unzip the installer for version 1.6 and FTP the files directly on top of the existing install, this is basically the same as using "/downloader". I think plesk has a file manager that will unpack zips in this way. Again the database is updated automatically.

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of this 'downloader'. I'll give it a go tonight. I suppose you mean this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/magento_installation_guide#installing_magento_using_the_downloader

Comment: It is intended for installing 3rd party extensions and updating them but because Magento is completely modular the core can also be updated in the same way, if you know the key.

Comment: It doesn't work. From a clean install of 1.5, I went to /downloader and logged in, typed the extension key and click Proceed. Starts installing and looks great. But then this:

CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Lib_Varien 1.6.1.0 depends on PHP extensions: Array ... Fatal error: Call to undefined method Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::isTableExists() ... Gah, stinky. Navigating to /downloader again: "dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract"... it's totally broken now. Sob :(

Comment: Looks like the version of PHP needed is not new enough. Until your host catches up all you can do is remove this install of Magento and start over. If you feel like getting another host then you have a chance to switch to Linux, it is [recommended](http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements).

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. The host is on PHP version 5.2.13, which is the same version as recommended. If this can't be resolved I will be giving up on Magento, I'm using my host for ASP.NET, so sticking with them however poor their support is.

Comment: Given up on Magento, decided to rewrite the whole thing in ASP.NET. At least then I have control...

Comment: I'm sure there must be plenty of .NET ecommerce choices. Good luck.